# An efficient way of exporting 10 datasets (each having 80 tables) from bigquery to google storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have 10 datasets in BigQuery and each dataset has 80 tables. I know I can export each table in each dataset one-by-one to google storage using console or Web UI. This is for back-up purposes. However, this would take a while.

I wonder if there is a more handy way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `bq` command line tools (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)

Following code will help you to achieve the same:

```
project="bigquery-project"
dataset="your-dataset"
bucket="your-bucket"

# get list of tables
tables=$(bq ls "$project:$dataset" | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)

for table in $tables
do
    bq extract --destination_format "CSV" --compression "GZIP" "$project:$dataset.$table" "gs://$bucket/$table/$table.csv.gz" 
done
```

Additionally, if you want to run command in `async` mode replace extract command with following

```
    bq --nosync extract --destination_format "CSV" --compression "GZIP" "$project:$dataset.$table" "gs://$bucket/$table/$table.csv.gz"
```

PS:

- Make sure that `bq` command line tools is installed and it is in your environment. It comes with `google cloud SDK`. To verify you can run `bq help`

Comment: is it possible to write multiple lines of code in command line with `bq` mode? For example, when I try this `# get list of tables
tables=$(bq ls "$project:$dataset" | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)`, I receive this error `unknown syntax`

Comment: Just save above script in a file, let say, `export_bq.sh` and execute it by running `bash export_bq.sh`. In case you want to run just single line replace parameters `$project:$dataset` with actual value

Comment: thanks for the answer! you mean I save it to my local or to the cloud? Are there any guides explaining this? For example, I could not find any resource of google cloud explaining the use of `bash` for running external scripts? Am I missing something, or there is not enough documentation on this?