# How to run an external script using bq command line tools

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have the following script stored in a file called `mycode.sh`, which will help me to copy an entire dataset to the storage.

```
project="bigquery-project"
dataset="your-dataset"
bucket="your-bucket"

# get list of tables
tables=$(bq ls "$project:$dataset" | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)

for table in $tables
do
    bq extract --destination_format "CSV" --compression "GZIP" "$project:$dataset.$table" "gs://$bucket/$table/$table.csv.gz" 
done
```

But, I do not know how to call this script from bq command line tools in my local computer.

Are there any guides explaining this? For example, I could not find any resource of google cloud explaining the use of bash for running external scripts? Am I missing something, or there is not enough documentation on this?

Comment: isn't this answered / commented already in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42927320/5221944 by @ShamshadAlam ?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant unfortunately it is not. That answer does not show how to run (or call) the script from `bq command line`.

Comment: This is a shell script - it should be called from shell itself, not from bq.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused. As Mosha has already pointed out, this is a shell script e.g `bash`. You cannot call a shell script from the `bq` too. It's the opposite way around - you call `bq` from a shell script. Mikhail is also right. This was clearly already answered in your original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An efficient way of exporting 10 datasets (each having 80 tables) from bigquery to google storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926433/an-efficient-way-of-exporting-10-datasets-each-having-80-tables-from-bigquery)